# After a system upgrade, when I `su -` I get bash-4.4 as a prompt instead of root@hostname

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, root, gnome-shell, prompt

I just upgraded my system. After logging in as root using `su -` there is no root username in my prompt, it's just `-bash-4.4#`

What should I do here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very easy to solve issue ;-)

The `PS1` variable is not properly set. This is done in the `/root/.bashrc`. Most likely the .bashrc was not updated or is broken in some other way. Replace it with the `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /root/.bashrc 
$ su -
root@desktop:~#
root@desktop:~# echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you very much :) Can you please also, tell me how should learn about these things. What resources should I use. Thank you again :)

Comment: I would say, that this is shell/bash knowledge. And since a lot of scripting in Linux base system is shell/bash, starting with some bash-tutorials is a good idea: https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/, https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/ and If you find that to easy: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/

Comment: @Amirtha There's always `man bash`, it defines PS1 through PS4 and has a Prompting section. Or just search for what you want yours to look like, and copy it